# c# HttpResponse BinaryWrite PDF working locally, but not on server

Tags: c#, pdf, httpresponse

I have a small C# Web Application that reads a PDF stored as BLOB data in a SQL table and serves it up in the browser to the user:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            byte[] data = GetData(Request.QueryString["companyNo"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["invoiceNo"].ToString());

            if (data != null)
            {
                Response.Buffer = true; 
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", data.Length.ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(data);
                Response.End();
            }
```

This work fine locally, but when I upload it to my test server, I get nothing back.

I've captured the traffic and can see locally, when you call the URL, it is doing an HTTP POST, but on the web server, its doing a GET and returning nothing.

**localhost Request Header**

Request POST /aff86f6621ed44b2910d856a19d0c8d1/browserLinkSignalR/abort?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAdyAqdSoaME6giXw9SxAo3gAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAABjumookEDHXn5Jz9JxDPjJAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAEzCAsIk2T%2Fm7voBY1V%2BeyooAAAAfF2pmaJ8A2WzK5JOx8QqKzYRYxFjyclkE3paKmoOPCXkIniBsjOhpxQAAAC8VGgsefZk5zRmUdh58GRu6xYAWQ%3D%3D&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64169%2FDefault.aspx&browserName=Internet+Explorer&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5

Accept  text/plain, */*; q=0.01

Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Referer http://localhost:64169/Default.aspx

Accept-Language en-GB

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; xs-cc6DYWKA8sA;rB12Ke; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Host    localhost:65187

Content-Length  0

DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache

**Server Request Header**

Request GET /MyApp/Default.aspx?companyNo=50222&invoiceNo=50497557 HTTP/1.1

Accept  image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*

Accept-Language en-GB

User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

Host    TestServer

Connection  Keep-Alive

I'm calling the same URL each time (with the exception of "TestServer" instead of "localhost". Is there some config I'm missing?

Comment: Since your response shows Content-Length 0, it seems GetData function is not returning any byte. Please put debug point on if (data != null) and check value for data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this header:

```
    fileName = "testFile";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                   string.Format("{0};FileName=\"{1}\"",
                                                 "attachment",
                                                 fileName));
```

Comment: Ive tried that before while googling around, and just tried it again to make sure, but no joy -- Same thing :(

Comment: What does it have this parameters locally and in the server? Request.QueryString["companyNo"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["invoiceNo"].ToString()

Comment: Can you add a debug line to print the data.length?

Answer (score 0):

Found what the issue was - I added a log to note specific events in the chain of the application as per Robeto & Mitesh's suggestion which allowed me to see that the function retrieving the data was falling over and returning no data due to lack of creds on the test box. Sorted this and data is coming back as expected now.

Thanks both for your support!